# Getting GOPATH error "go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: go, gopath

I'm unable to run `go get git@github<user/repo>` in my `$GOPATH` folder.
Getting this error:

> go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode

I just want to understand why `go get` isn't working even though `$GOPATH` is configured during the installation. Environment is ubuntu.

```
~/$ echo $GOPATH
/home/user/go
```

Comment: Have you tried `go get github.com/user/repo`?

Comment: The issue was with the repo format, instead of `git@github<user/repo>` i had to use `github.com/<user>/<repo>`

Comment: sync you go mod it will fix the issue . Make sure not to repeat the dependency

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you already noticed, you should use `go get github.com/<user>/<repo>`.

The error message you saw comes from a new feature implemented in `go get` to support [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) - you can now also specify the version of a dependency: `go get github.com/<user>/<repo>@<version>`, where `version` is a git tag using semver, e.g. `v1.0.2`.

Answer (score 68):

I had the same issue and solved setting specific env variable `export GO111MODULE=on` in my .zshrc(or .bashrc depending on which shell you use) and restart the shell in order to enable modules. You can find more details here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: I'm not sure this actually solves the issue?! I mean, this env variable disables "GOPATH mode" (which is disabled by default anyway starting with Go v1.13), but `git@github<user/repo>` still isn't "path@version syntax", so it still wouldn't work?

Comment: Google must have enabled it by default in 1.14 or 1.15 because I get this error message with 1.15. I do see there is a pull request to fix this yet again in 1.16. This things changes way to frequently to keep up.

Comment: Actually, since go version 1.16 the `GO111MODULE=on` is set by default.

Answer (score 21):

I met this issue, too. After some search, the following works by using `go mod` instead of `go get`, which is a feature of [Golang Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules):

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on

$ go mod init <project name>

# go mod init HelloWorld
# or
# go mod init .

$ go mod download repo@version

# go mod download github.com/robfig/cron/v3@v3.0.0
```

Answer (score 10):

I got this error with Go v1.14 when running `$ go get github.com/<user>/<repo>@<version>` on an empty project before I had initialized my project with modules.

To resolve, I created a `go.mod` file using:

`$ go mod init`

I was able to rerun the get command successfully, which downloaded the vendor's package, updated the `go.mod` file, and created a `go.sum` file.

Comment: This worked for me to get buffalo to install correctly on Mac OS with golang 1.15.8 (https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/getting-started/installation#custom-installation-with-sqlite3-support)

Answer (score 8):

Update version of go following instructions at https://gist.github.com/nikhita/432436d570b89cab172dcf2894465753

This worked for me!

Comment: In a more "Ubuntu way", it worked for me following this article https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-go-on-centos-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

If you get this error while you trying use modules, you should change dir to project before go get:

```
root@host:/# go get github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang/ibmmq@ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
root@host:/# cd myproject/
root@host:/myproject# ls go.mod 
go.mod
root@host:/myproject# go get github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang/ibmmq@ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
go: finding github.com ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
go: finding github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang/ibmmq ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
go: finding github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
go: finding github.com/ibm-messaging ff54c095001d81eed10615916a896512eb8d81ff
```

Comment: This works if you are using a newer version of Go (1.14+) and your legacy Go project is not ready to move into go modules yet. It's a nice way to install a tool globally. But you have to use `go install` instead, and make sure that `echo $GOBIN` prints something like `~/go/bin` (and that GOBIN is in your PATH), so it still works like it used to in older versions of Go

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this issue when i tried running the command in a directory outside of the directory where go mod is initialized. In order to download a module with a specific version go requires go.mod file which can keep track of multiple version of a same module. However trying to download the module in anywhere else outside of a go module directory(where GOPATH will be referenced to store the download module) will fail as there is no option to keep track of different versions of the same module.